# Facelets: any library that ships templates?

Tags: templates, jsf-2, jar, facelets

Like in the title, is there any lib like PrimeFaces or RichFaces that is template-oriented?

I'm building my own including some fixed/liquid/elastic base layouts but I wonder if someone out there has already done this boring work.

**UPDATE**

i'm sorry, i haven't explained myself.
i'm talking about a sort of framework on framework made by a tree of templates (and optionally beans).
i'm currently using this root template, that is bundled in a jar file with some bean and , entity, for all my applications:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="#{localeBean.locale.language}" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:s="http://shapeitalia.com/jsf2" 
    xmlns:sc="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/shape">

    <f:view locale="#{localeBean.locale}">
        <h:head>
            <title><ui:insert name="module"/> - <ui:insert name="title"/></title>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="#{resource['shape/favicon/shape.ico']}" />
            <h:outputStylesheet library="shape" name="css/core.css" />
            <h:outputStylesheet library="shape" name="css/fileicons.css" />
            <h:outputScript library="shape" name="js/jquery.jsPlumb-1.3.15-all.js" />
            <h:outputScript library="shape" name="js/core.js" />
        </h:head>

        <h:body>
            <ui:debug hotkey="x" />
            <p:growl id="messages" globalOnly="false" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" showSummary="true" />

            <p:ajaxStatus onstart="statusDialog.show();" onsuccess="statusDialog.hide();" />

            <p:dialog modal="true" widgetVar="statusDialog" header="loading..." resizable="false" closable="false">
                <h:graphicImage library="shape" name="images/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
            </p:dialog>

            <div>
                <ui:insert name="header">
                    <h:form>
                        <s:panelGrid cellStyle="border: 0;">
                            <s:column style="text-align: left;">
                                <p:commandLink action="index" >
                                    <h:graphicImage library="shape" name="images/shape.png" height="30px" style="vertical-align: middle; float: left; border: 0"/>
                                </p:commandLink>
                            </s:column>
                            <s:column style="text-align: right;">
                                <p:menuButton rendered="#{not empty request.userPrincipal}" value="#{request.userPrincipal.name}" style="float: right">
                                    <p:menuitem actionListener="#{sessionBean.logout}" action="index" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-power" value="#{bundle.logout}"/>
                                </p:menuButton>
                            </s:column>
                        </s:panelGrid>
                    </h:form>
                </ui:insert>
            </div>

            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{not empty request.userPrincipal}">
                <ui:insert name="content">insert content here</ui:insert>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup rendered="#{empty request.userPrincipal}">
                <h:form>
                    <p:panel header="login">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                            <h:outputLabel for="login_email" value="Email:" />
                            <h:outputLabel for="login_password" value="Password:" />
                            <h:panelGroup />

                            <p:inputText id="login_email" value="#{requestScope.email}" label="email" size="32"/>
                            <p:password id="login_password" value="#{requestScope.password}" label="password" feedback="false" size="32"/>
                            <p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{sessionBean.login}" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-check" ajax="false"/>

                            <p:message for="login_email" />
                            <p:message for="login_password" />
                            <h:panelGroup />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>


            <ui:insert name="external" />

        </h:body>
    </f:view>
</html>
```

and this is only the root one.

i'd like to know if is there someone who has already done a work like this and have bundled it

Comment: Layout is a matter of HTML/CSS, not Facelets. Facelets is just there to keep the HTML as DRY as possible with help of templating.

Comment: What you've there is not exactly a globally reuseable layout template. It wouldn't be reuseable on the layout as used by for example Google, Facebook, Twitter or Stack Overflow. In other words, the layout is very specific to your own applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok there is no such a thing.

the best out there are components like `p:layout`.